# Proving curried and uncurried functions

Tags: lambda-calculus

We are given

$$
\underline{add} \ \underline{m} \ \underline{n} = \underline{m+n}
$$
$$
\underline{mult} \ \underline{m} \ \underline{n} = \underline{m \times n}
$$

and

$$
\underline{sum} \ (\underline{m}, \underline{n}) = \underline{m+n}
$$
$$
\underline{prod} \ (\underline{m}, \underline{n}) = \underline{m \times n}
$$

where $\underline{sum}$ is said to be an uncurried version of $\underline{add}$ and similarly $\underline{prod}$ is an uncurried version of $\underline{mult}$ such that

$$
\underline{sum} = \underline{uncurry} \ \underline{add}
$$
$$
\underline{prod} = \underline{uncurry} \ \underline{mult}
$$

where

$$
\underline{curry} = \lambda fx_1 x_2. f (x_1, x_2)
$$
$$
\underline{uncurry} = \lambda fp. f (\underline{fst} \ p) (\underline{snd} \ p)
$$

## The question

The question starts by giving properties that

$$
\underline{curry} (\underline{uncurry} \ E) = E
$$
$$
\underline{uncurry} (\underline{curry} \ E) = E
$$

And I am to use this to show that:

$$
\underline{add} = \underline{curry} \ \underline{sum}
$$
$$
\underline{mult} = \underline{curry} \ \underline{prod}
$$

## My answer

(i) It would be sufficient to show that $(\underline{curry} \ \underline{sum})\underline{m} \ \underline{n} = \underline{m+n}$.

But $\underline{add} = \underline{curry} (\underline{uncurry} \ \underline{add}) = \underline{curry} \ \underline{sum}$.

So we need to show that $(\underline{curry} (\underline{uncurry} \ \underline{add})) \underline{m} \ \underline{n} = \underline{m+n}$.

Let's go!

$((\lambda f x_1 x_2. f (x_1, x_2)) ( (\lambda fp. f (\underline{fst} \ p)(\underline{snd} \ p)) \ \underline{add} )) \underline{m} \ \underline{n}
= ((\lambda fx_1 x_2. f(x_1, x_2)) (\lambda p. \underline{add} (\underline{fst} \ p)(\underline{snd} \ p)) \underline{m} \ \underline{n}
= (\lambda x_1 x_2. (\lambda p. \underline{add} (\underline{fst} \ p)(\underline{snd} \ p))(x_1, x_2)) \underline{m} \ \underline{n}
= (\lambda x_1 x_2. \underline{add} \ x_1 \ x_2) \underline{m} \ \underline{n}
= \underline{add} \ \underline{m} \ \underline{n}
= \underline{m+n}$

(ii) It would be sufficient to show that $(\underline{curry} \ \underline{prod}) \underline{m} \ \underline{n} = \underline{m \times n}$.

But $\underline{mult} = \underline{curry} (\underline{uncurry} \ \underline{mult}) = \underline{curry} \ \underline{prod}$.

So we need to show that $(\underline{curry} (\underline{uncurry} \ \underline{mult})) \underline{m} \ \underline{n} = \underline{m \times n}$.

Let's do it!

$((\lambda f x_1 x_2. f(x_1, x_2)) ((\lambda fp. f(\underline{fst} \ p)(\underline{snd} \ p)) \underline{mult})) \underline{m} \ \underline{n}
= ((\lambda fx_1 x_2. f(x_1, x_2)) (\lambda p. \underline{mult} (\underline{fst} \ p)(\underline{snd} \ p))) \underline{m} \ \underline{n}
= (\lambda x_1 x_2. (\lambda p. \underline{mult} (\underline{fst} \ p)(\underline{snd} \ p)) (x_1, x_2)) \underline{m} \ \underline{n}
= (\lambda x_1 x_2. \underline{mult} \ x_1 x_2) \underline{m} \ \underline{n}
= \underline{mult} \ \underline{m} \ \underline{n}
= \underline{m \times n}$

$\square$

Are the steps correct and reasonable? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: In your definition of $=$, are you allowed to also use $=_\eta$? Eta-equvialence is the equivalence relation that is contextually closed and contains the relation $\lambda x.Mx =_\eta M$ whenever the variable $x$ is not free in $M$.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco yeh i guess you could use that too :)

Comment: Basically, if your definition of $=$ includes $=_\eta$, then what you did is correct. Otherwise, it is not.

Comment: Yeh of course it's allowed.